# Changing color of element depending on dynamic value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I want to change the color on a button which displays a value which is fetched from a database. The value can be between -10 and 10.
I would like to display 5 shades of red and 5 shades of green.

This is what I've come up with so far:

**html**

```
            <button class="scoreTicker">{{ $score }} </button>
```

**js**

```
            var scoreTicker = parseInt($('.scoreTicker').innerHTML());

            if(scoreTicker < 0){
                $('.scoreTicker').css('background', 'red');
            }
            else(scoreTicker > 0){
                $('.scoreTicker').css('background', 'green');
            }
```

I was thinking of making elseif statements for every shade, this would result in 10 conditional statements which seems a bit overkill. Is there a smarter way of doing this?

Comment: You might find my solution interesting if you don't want to pre-define your colors in an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an array of RGB or HEX codes and index it in such a way that your button value would represent the index of a color in the array. So you would end up using it in such a way:

```
$('.scoreTicker').css('background-color', colors[buttonValue]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using shades of a color, you can calculate the hex code based on the scoreTicker value like so:

```js
$(".scoreTicker input").on("input", function() {
  var scoreTicker = parseInt($(this).val());
  var color = {
    red: 0,
    green: 0,
    blue: 0
  };
  if (scoreTicker >= 0) {
    // green
    color.green = 25.5 * Math.abs(scoreTicker);
  } else {
    // red
    color.red = 25.5 * Math.abs(scoreTicker);
  }

  $('.scoreTicker').css('background', "rgb(" + color.red + ", " + color.green + ", " + color.blue + ")");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scoreTicker">
  <input class="scoreTicker" type="range" min="-10" max="10" step="2" />
</div>
```